# How to delete the second column from this input?

Tags: bash, awk

```
INPUT
bix.hu.         42433   IN  A   193.239.149.1
bix.hu.         42433   IN  MX  10 deneb.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         42433   IN  NS  ns.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         42433   IN  NS  ns.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         42433   IN  NS  ns-s.nic.hu.
bix.hu.         42433   IN  NS  ns-s.nic.hu.
bix.hu.         42433   IN  SOA ns.iszt.hu. hostmaster.iszt.hu. 2011053000 28800 7200 604800 14400

OUTPUT
bix.hu.         IN  A   193.239.149.1
bix.hu.         IN  MX  10 deneb.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns-s.nic.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns-s.nic.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  SOA ns.iszt.hu. hostmaster.iszt.hu. 2011053000 28800 7200 604800 14400
```

using bash, sed, awk, etc. How??

actually it's just an output from:

```
dig -t any bix.hu | egrep -v "^;;|^;|^$" | sort
```

I just don't want the TTL column.. [because I want to sha256sum the output, and in this way I can check that the DNS settings are modified or not, but if the TTL keeps decreasing it ruins the sha256sum] - it will be just a checker script..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

KISS and use the `+nottlid` option? [`man dig`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/dig/).

```
-----[ 16:44:51 ] (!4302) [ :-) ] janmoesen@janbookpro ~ 
$ dig -t any bix.hu | egrep -v "^;;|^;|^$" | sort
bix.hu.         43113   IN  A   193.239.149.1
bix.hu.         43113   IN  MX  10 deneb.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         43113   IN  NS  ns-s.nic.hu.
bix.hu.         43113   IN  NS  ns.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         43113   IN  SOA ns.iszt.hu. hostmaster.iszt.hu. 2011053000 28800 7200 604800 14400
-----[ 16:44:53 ] (!4303) [ :-) ] janmoesen@janbookpro ~ 
$ dig +nottlid -t any bix.hu | egrep -v "^;;|^;|^$" | sort
bix.hu.         IN  A   193.239.149.1
bix.hu.         IN  MX  10 deneb.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns-s.nic.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  SOA ns.iszt.hu. hostmaster.iszt.hu. 2011053000 28800 7200 604800 14400
```

You should really check out the documentation. For example, you can tell dig to only print the relevant info, so that grepping is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`cut(1)` is your friend:

```
dig -t any bix.hu | egrep -v "^;;|^;|^$" | sort | cut -c1-16,22-
```